# Pandas: Create New Dataframe that Counts Number of Times Keywords / Phrases From List Occur in One Column

Tags: list, pandas, search, count, frequency

I have the following word list:

list = ['clogged drain', 'right wing', 'horse', 'bird', 'collision light']

I have the following data frame (notice spacing can be weird):

```
ID  TEXT               
1   you have   clogged   drain     
2   the dog   has a right wing   clogged drain     
3   the  bird flew  into collision light       
4   the horse is here to horse   around   
5   bird    bird bird
```

I want to create a table that shows keywords and frequency counts of how often the keywords occurred in TEXT field.  However, if a keyword appears more than once in the same row within the TEXT column, it is only counted once.

Desired output:

```
keywords         count
clogged drain    2
right wing       1
horse            1
bird             2
collision light  1
```

I have searched all over stackoverflow but couldn't find my specific case.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by reformatting the `TEXT` column to get rid of your funny spacing, using `str.split()` and `str.join()`. Then, use `str.contains` for each of your keywords, and get the sum of the boolean values that are outputted (It will return `True` if your keyword is found):

```
# Reformat text, splitting wherever you have one or more spaces
df['formatted_text'] = df.TEXT.str.split('\s+').str.join(' ')

# create your output dataframe
df2 = pd.DataFrame(my_list, columns=['keywords'])

# Count occurences:
df2['count'] = df2['keywords'].apply(lambda x: df.formatted_text.str.contains(x).sum())
```

The result:

```
>>> df2
          keywords  count
0    clogged drain      2
1       right wing      1
2            horse      1
3             bird      2
4  collision light      1
```

Just to note, I changed the variable name of your `list` to `my_list`, so as not to mask the built in python data type

Answer (score 0):

You can using `extractall`

```
df.TEXT.str.extractall(r'({})'.format('|'.join(list)))[0].str.get_dummies().sum(level=0).gt(0).astype(int).sum()
Out[225]: 
bird               2
clogged drain      2
collision light    1
horse              1
right wing         1
dtype: int64
```